# Nifi data movement between SQL databases to HDFS and Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-nifi, cloudera

In Nifi I have flows that copy information from SQL databases (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.) to HIVE,
where after depositing the .avro files in HDFS and defining an .avsc (manually),
I build an external table (used as temp table) to finally copy that table´s data to a final table managed by HIVE
stored as parquet and with snappy compression.

At the moment my flows are like the following:

```
GenerateFlowFile -> 
DeleteHDFS (delete avro files in HDFS from previous flows execution) -> 
ExecuteSQL (get new avro data) -> 
PutHDFS (avro files to HDFS) -> 
ReplaceText (empty the flowfile data) -> 
MergeContent (e.g., 28 flowfiles generated by ExecuteSQL are merged into 1 flowfile) -> 
ReplaceText (DROP AND CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE - pointing to avro data and avsc file) -> 
PutHiveQL -> 
ReplaceText (INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_TABLE) -> 
PutHiveQL
```

I would like to know if this approach is the right one for moving data between these environments
or if there is a better way to do it (more effective and efficient).

I'd like to reduce the number of processors in my Nifi dataflows and if possible, improve the efficiency in data movement.

Comment: Seems fine. Others may prefer using Debezium and Kafka to stream the data in real time rather than do bulk uploads.